# Localize Attributes (storeview values) programmatically

Tags: localisation

Because i have many options (read 10k+) for some of the attributes, it is a real pain to update/change/add the attribute titles on a per storeview base. Mostly it is not even possible to save the attributes.
Is there a way to do it programmatically or by plain sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it's best to do direct queries because of the massive amount of options. But even re indexing is going to be a challenge.

I'm not sure about Magento EE but on Magento CE you're bound to run into issues I would guess.
Maybe it's worthwhile to see if you can split up some attributes into multiple attributes each assigned to a different attribute set. Is there really a product that comes in 10k+ variations?

Comment: it is planned for the future to split the attributes, but not the really near future :(
In which table is the localisation taking place?

Comment: `eav_attribute_option_value` holds the values and their store ID's

Comment: Oh i did not meant the to translate the option values but the attribute name itself.

Comment: If you check the database you'll see there's a table called `eav_attribute_label`. This is for that attribute label translations

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hoped it would be that table and tried it before, but because of a typo in the attribute_id field it did not work as expected.